# How to set up a Castle Siege?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, encounter-design, gm-preparation

I am running a war, for my players. They have won a battle pushing their opponent back into a citadel within the cliffs.

I am looking for stories, suggestions, or more importantly rules on how to run a siege encounter.

Comment: What is your party's composition, and what is their siege strategy? Also, what is the logistical pipeline for both sides like?

Comment: Also: [Related problem](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67976/how-can-i-avoid-making-extended-prolonged-encounters-boring?rq=1)

Comment: You haven't given us any criteria to evaluate which answers are best, and you're also shopping for suggestions and ideas. Both of those things are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some starting points you can find on the [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/):

### For the citadel:

- http://www.d20srd.org/srd/wilderness.htm#wallsAndGates;
- http://www.d20srd.org/srd/wilderness.htm#guardsAndSoldiers; and
- a google search led me to the [DMG Web enhancement: Building a City](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111231228/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20030719a).

You might want to use thicker and higher walls and larger number of soldiers than the size of the citadel suggests, since citadels are build with defensibility as an important goal.

### For the players (siegers) you have:

- http://www.d20srd.org/srd/wilderness.htm#siegeEngines; and
- http://www.d20srd.org/srd/wilderness.htm#mountainTerrain

### For both the besieged and the siegers:

- Siege battles can be about resources; see
  http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#starvationAndThirst

## Suggestions

Create opportunities for special missions for the player characters:

- A scout mission to find weak points in the city's defenses;
- Destroy or poison the enemy's supplies;
- A sapper mission exploring a cave passage which may allow destroying a section of wall;
- Chase and catch a courier that left the city to request reinforcements.